# Как закрасить бордер в 2 разных цвета?

Tags: html, css, css3

Всем привет! Есть у меня в блоке нижний бордер. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы первые `100px` были цвета исходного, а остальная часть границы - оранжевого цвета. Можно это сделать средствами css3 не добавляя лишних блоков с наслоениями цветов?

```css
.stripe {
  border-bottom:2px solid #c37488;
  max-width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stripe">
  полоска
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

можно так

```css
.stripe {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #c37488;
  max-width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.stripe:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="stripe">
  полоска
</div>
```

или так

```css
.stripe {    
    max-width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
.stripe:before,
.stripe:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 100%; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 2px;
}
.stripe:before{   
    left: 0;
    background: #c37488;    
}
.stripe:after{
    right: 0;    
    background: orange;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="stripe">
  полоска
</div>
```

и тот же вариант, но без использования calc:

```css
.stripe {    
    max-width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
.stripe:before,
.stripe:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; 
    height: 2px;
}
.stripe:before{   
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    max-width: 100%; /* А вдруг весь div был меньше */
    background: #c37488;    
}
.stripe:after{
    left: 100px;
    right: 0;
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="stripe">
  полоска
</div>
```

вариант с градиентом

```css
.stripe {
    max-width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
.stripe:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #c37488;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #c37488 0%, #c37488 100px, #ffa500 100px, #ffa500 100px, #ffa500 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #c37488), color-stop(100px, #c37488), color-stop(100px, #ffa500), color-stop(100px, #ffa500), color-stop(100%, #ffa500));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #c37488 0%, #c37488 100px, #ffa500 100px, #ffa500 100px, #ffa500 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #c37488 0%, #c37488 100px, #ffa500 100px, #ffa500 100px, #ffa500 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #c37488 0%, #c37488 100px, #ffa500 100px, #ffa500 100px, #ffa500 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #c37488 0%, #c37488 100px, #ffa500 100px, #ffa500 100px, #ffa500 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#c37488', endColorstr='#ffa500', GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div class="stripe">полоска</div>
```

Comment: `border:1px` вместо `border-bottom:2px` приводит к более жирной линии при уменьшении масштаба. <s>Советую поменять.</s> Опоздал, ты уже сам поменял :)

Comment: @soledar10 супер! спасибо

Comment: @Вася, а говорил, без наслоения цветов... UPDATE: Не заметил второй вариант.

Comment: А зачем задавать ширину через calc, если можно вместо этого одновременно указать left и right?

Comment: @Qwertiy вы меня превратно поняли - я писал
"не добавляя лишних блоков с наслоениями цветов", а :before и :footer - это псевдоэлементы, а не блоки)
а как это - с помощью left и right?

Comment: @Вася, добавил в этот ответ.

Comment: @Вася, что касается наслоения, то в первом варианте псевдоэлемент показывался поверх границы - при каких-то значениях масштаба это могло оказаться заметным.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так. Ещё надо проверить, какие префиксы и в каких местах (border-image/linear-gradient) нужны для кроссбраузерности. Ещё убедиться в поддержке currentColor, возможно, стоит заменить его на нужный цвет.

```css
.stripe {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  max-width: 300px;
  color: green;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, currentColor 0%, currentColor 100px, orange 100px, orange 100%) 0 0 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="stripe">
  полоска
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на 4 цвета. Таким образом можно сделать сколько угодно.

```
.stripe {

border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #be6767 0%, #be6767 25%, #38c695 25%, #38c695 50%, #b27cf5 50%, #b27cf5 75%, #feb960 75%, #feb960 100%) 1 1;
}
```