# Раскрасить полоску в разные цвета

Tags: html, css, css3, градиент

Всем привет! В продолжение [темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444341/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2-2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0/444345#444345) хочу закрасить полоску в 150px (первые 50px - фиолетовые, вторые 50px - оранжевые,третье 50px тоже фиолетовые)
Создаю с помощью css3 конструктора, но вся полоска у меня почему-то однотонная..

```css
.main-hr {
  width: 150px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #c37488;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c37488 1%, #c37488 32%, #f0b283 32%, #f0b283 33%, #f0b283 34%, #f0b283 66%, #f0b283 66%, #f0b283 67%, #f0b283 67%, #c37488 67%, #c37488 67%, #c37488 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%, #c37488), color-stop(32%, #c37488), color-stop(32%, #f0b283), color-stop(33%, #f0b283), color-stop(34%, #f0b283), color-stop(66%, #f0b283), color-stop(66%, #f0b283), color-stop(67%, #f0b283), color-stop(67%, #f0b283), color-stop(67%, #c37488), color-stop(67%, #c37488), color-stop(100%, #c37488), color-stop(100%, #f0b283), color-stop(100%, #f0b283), color-stop(100%, #f0b283), color-stop(100%, #f0b283));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c37488 1%, #c37488 32%, #f0b283 32%, #f0b283 33%, #f0b283 34%, #f0b283 66%, #f0b283 66%, #f0b283 67%, #f0b283 67%, #c37488 67%, #c37488 67%, #c37488 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c37488 1%, #c37488 32%, #f0b283 32%, #f0b283 33%, #f0b283 34%, #f0b283 66%, #f0b283 66%, #f0b283 67%, #f0b283 67%, #c37488 67%, #c37488 67%, #c37488 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c37488 1%, #c37488 32%, #f0b283 32%, #f0b283 33%, #f0b283 34%, #f0b283 66%, #f0b283 66%, #f0b283 67%, #f0b283 67%, #c37488 67%, #c37488 67%, #c37488 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c37488 1%, #c37488 32%, #f0b283 32%, #f0b283 33%, #f0b283 34%, #f0b283 66%, #f0b283 66%, #f0b283 67%, #f0b283 67%, #c37488 67%, #c37488 67%, #c37488 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#c37488', endColorstr='#f0b283', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div class="main-hr"></div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/pm97820r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Она не однородная, просто градиент вертикальный.
Сделал только для w3c, с остальными генератор поможет - я их синтаксис не помню.

Кстати, почему начало 1%, а не 0? И что-то у тебя в нём лишних точек много.
Твой вариант закомментирован, поправленный добавлен.

```css
.main-hr {
  width: 150px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #c37488;
  /*background: linear-gradient(to right, #c37488 1%, #c37488 32%, #f0b283 32%, #f0b283 33%, #f0b283 34%, #f0b283 66%, #f0b283 66%, #f0b283 67%, #f0b283 67%, #c37488 67%, #c37488 67%, #c37488 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%, #f0b283 100%);*/
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #c37488 0%, #c37488 33%, #f0b283 33%, #f0b283 67%, #c37488 67%, #c37488 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-hr"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Там, где градиент создаете поставьте направление по горизонтали. А то у вас сейчас сверху вниз